# Arrange files in custom order windows explorer Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

In Windows XP, you could arrange drag and drop to arrange files in windows explorer, Like so:

January Report
February Report
March Report
April Report

I have not been able to do this in windows 7, 8, or 10 (Current).  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The option seems to be moved. IanCost's [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-has-the-option-to-arrange-photos-by/030d3854-433d-433d-8a2e-126dc8dd5407) shows the location of these options.

Comment: no, custom ordering is removed in Explorer since Windows 7. Last Windows was Vista where could do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible since Windows 7. Here Microsoft needed to re-write the Explorer control to support the library feature. [And here Microsoft decided that the feature was not used by a lot of users](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/766326-disable-auto-arrange-in-folder-view/#comment-590933708) and so they have not re-implemented it.

> Windows 7 includes a brand new view control for items in the Explorer.
>   Given time constraints, certain functionality that was deemed lower
>   priority wasn't able to be implemented in the new control.

So send feedback to Microsoft via the [Feedback Hub app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/feedback-hub/9nblggh4r32n) and hope you get enough votes that Microsoft implements it in a newer Windows 10 Feature Update.

Comment: That is not the answer I was looking for, but it is correct. Thanks!

Comment: Well, now probably the only workaround to customize files order here is to rename files with a numeric or alphabetic prefix like 01 02 02 ... aa ab ac ad ... za zb zc etc.  (if it's acceptable and there are not too many files to rename)